# Populating a drop-down from a database in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am having a jsp page containing a form for add ne item to a system. In there, I need to select the category that the new item belongs to. I need to populate this drop-down list from a database using spring. For the form submission, I am writing a controller class called ItemController.java where the drop-down element is which I need to populate. But, that populating list items need to be called from another controller class named CategoryController.java. I tried so many ways but still I could not able to do it as still getting errors. anybody can have a look on this please?

Here are my codes.

addItem.jsp

```
  <form:form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="frmAddItem" action="/admin/items/add_item" method="post" commandName="command">
    <fieldset class="scheduler-border">

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
    <label for="selectCat" class="col-xs-3 control-label">
       Category
    </label>

    <div class="col-xs-5">

    <form:select class="form-control" id="selectCat" path="categoryName">
    <form:option value="-" label="--Select Category--"/>
    <form:options items="${listCat}" />
    </form:select>
      <span id="catErr" class="input-group-error"></span>
    </div>........
```

ItemController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/items")
public class ItemController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(ItemController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository item;

    @Qualifier("categoryRepository")
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository category;

    /**
     * Add new item view
     */

    //For viewing the add item form
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showAddItem() {
        return new ModelAndView("addItem", "command", new Item());
    }

    //For submitting the add new item
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add_item")
    public String addItem(@ModelAttribute("newItem") Item newItem) throws SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException {

    System.out.println("First Name:" + newItem.getItemName());

    int a = item.add(newItem);
    if (a == 1)
       return "redirect:add";
       // model.setViewName("addItem");
     else

     // System.out.println("Error in item add");
     return "redirect:add";
     //  return model;
    }
```

CategoryController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/items")
public class CategoryController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(CategoryController.class);

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository item;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showAddItem() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        List<Map<String, Object>> listCat = categoryRepository.viewCategoryList();
        model.addObject("listCat", listCat);
        return new ModelAndView("addItem", "command", new Item());
    }
```

Comment: it looks like you have mapping /items/add mapped to two different controllers

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/ your problem is you are having list of map. In this example has only map of key value pairs.I think you have to loop list.Within loop you can try <form:options items="${listCat}" /> kind of code or option tag with key & value

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to add 2 models to the `ModelAndView` object inside the `showAddItem` method in `CategoryController` class, which will not work if you want to add multiple objects to `ModelAndView` you can use a `Map` or just use `Model` class instead.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String showAddItem(Model model) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> listCat =   categoryRepository.viewCategoryList();
    model.addAttribute("listCat",listCat);
    model.addAttribute("command",new Item());
    return "addItem";
 }
```

since you are trying to populate a dropdown from a `List of Maps` you might wanna change the current code inside the jsp.

```
<select name='lists'>  
   <c:forEach var="list" items="${listCat}">
       <option id="${list.key}" value="${list.value.getName()}">${list.value.getName()}</option>   
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

change the commandname attribute inside the form too

```
commandName="command"
```

Comment: showAddItem(ModelAndView modelandview)` is returning a ` return new ModelAndView("addItem", "model", model);` . When I change the `String` into `ModelAndView` then it gives this error. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute` .

Comment: can you have look on this please? I tried it so many ways but still I am struggling with this..

Comment: made some changes to the code removed modelAndView and just went with Model instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with the Oracle XE sample database. When I update an employee I want to be able to select their manager_id from a list of names. Here's how I did it...

1. get a list of managers, employees who have subordinates. To achieve this I added a query to the repository. Note - you need to return all the fields to allow the entity to be populated.

```
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(manager_id) FROM employees)", nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Employee> findAllManagers();
```

2. In the controller I fetched the list of managers and added it to the model.

```
    @GetMapping("/update")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@RequestParam("employeeId") int employeeId, Model model) {
        
        Employee employee = service.findById(employeeId);
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        
        List<Employee> managers = service.findAllManagers();
        model.addAttribute("managers", managers);
        
        return "employees/form";
    }
```

3. In the form I used the list of managers to construct a drop down list.

```
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{manager.employeeId}" id="managers">
    <option th:each="manager : ${managers}" th:value="${manager.employeeId}" th:text="${manager.lastName} + ', ' + ${manager.firstName}"></option>
</select>
```

That's what worked for me at time of writing. Luck.